# Why are PowerShell Import-Module wildcards not working?

Tags: powershell, import, module, powercli

I have a few scripts where I import all VMware-Modules for simplicity. This has worked all the time - but now on one server it won't.

```
PS C:\Temp> Import-Module VMware.*
Import-Module : The specified module 'VMware.*' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module VMware.*
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (VMware.*:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I just copied the modules to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`.

When I use the full name (`Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core`) it works as usual.

How can I fix this? They appear correctly when I do a `Get-Module -ListAvailable`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) doesn't support wildcards. What you could do, however, is get all the module names using [`Get-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-Module) and then pipe them into a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) command.

I believe this will achieve what you are after:

```
Get-Module -Name "VMWave.*" | ForEach-Object { Import-Module $_; Write-Host "Imported Module $_"}
```